# ANDROID store new contact in phone instead of google account?

Tags: android, google-contacts

android 6. i imported contacts from a .VCF, they are all "phone contacts", probably because there was no google account yet. when i try to add a new contact it adds it to the google account. i don't see a way of changing that, other than deleting the GA from the phone, which would make it impossible to install apps. is there? i am not interested in a solution that moves all the contacts to the google account.

Answer (score 1):

All android devices with lollipop and above android versions will give you option to change the location where the contacts will be saved just change it while saving [image1 click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1OMs.png) [image 2 click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dwsn.png)

here i am including images of device running on android 7.0 in 1 pic device asks us to choose local or to add google account

choose local to save in device storage....,

if your issue is not resolve comment it i am ready to help...

Comment: my mistake. i'll post in a android forum instead. however, I think the images posted by responder are what I would see if I deleted the google account, but not otherwise.